# How do I create multiple api calls with angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am currently creating a Twitch streaming app that allows users to see if a channel is being streamed. The problem that I am facing is for the project I am using Angularjs. The problem is that I have an array of users for the web application but don't know how to call the api multiple times using angular js. Here is what I have so far

```
var freecodecamp=[];//Contains users 
angular.module("twitchController",[])
.controller($scope,$http){
```

`$scope.handler=function()//api call here`}`

Here is the link to my codepen

http://codepen.io/whatisthis/pen/WwLYOM 
Thanks in advance!=]

Comment: A little bit more information would be helpful. I.e. can you send all names in one call? If you want to call the controller multiply times, you could write a for loop and execute the $http.jsonp() freecodecamp.length times.

Comment: can you please elaborate ? why do you wana call API multiple time ? and what is it you are trying accomplish.

Comment: I believe that I want to send all the names in one call then use the ng-repeat to print them to the screen

Comment: Look at the documentation for $q.all()